# Python - Folium map don't show marker

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, marker, folium

I have this code in python and show map.

```
import folium
from IPython.display import HTML, display

city_location = [-23.6573395, -46.5322504]

mapa = folium.Map(location=city_location,  zoom_start=15)
mapa
```

But, to add marker, don't show.

```
tooltip = 'Click me!'
folium.Marker([-23.6573395, -46.5322504], popup='<i>Teste</i>', tooltip=tooltip).add_to(mapa)
mapa
```

Help me, please!

Answer (score 2):

Using python3, this code gives me the expected result:

```
import folium
city_location = [-23.6573395, -46.5322504]

m = folium.Map(location=city_location,
               zoom_start=15,
               tiles='openstreetmap')

folium.Marker(city_location,
              popup='<i>Teste</i>', 
              tooltip='Click me!').add_to(m)

m
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this line:

```
mapa.save('path')
```